# Have the bar at the top move down with you

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, top-bar

On some sites the bar at the top will move down with you when you move down the page. I think that something like this might look nice on Stack Exchange.

What I mean is for this bar:

[image: Top SE Bar]

To move down the page with you as you move down the page, and up when you move up the page so that you can always access it however far down the page you are.
Is this something that SE might implement?

Comment: +1 It's small enough I don't think it would cause a problem viewing the pages and would be really nice to have. Shouldn't be hard to implement either.

Answer (score 0):

I made [a userscript](https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-collection/blob/master/customizations/topbar.user.js) a while ago that does this. It's a tad buggy on a few sites such as [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) and [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/), though.

To install, make sure you have Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey, then visit [this page](https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-collection/raw/master/customizations/topbar.user.js).

Comment: @PatrickHofman s/love/move/, but yes.

Comment: Indeed @nathan. Stupid auto replace... I would suggest to move your answer to the duplicate target.